# Is there a way to migrate EF in .netstandard with Xamarin.Forms package?

Tags: entity-framework, xamarin.forms, entity-framework-core, .net-standard

I have a .netstandard Model layer that referenced from Xamarin.forms.

I set Xamarin.Forms package in Model layer => PrivateAssets="All".

My .netstandard Data layer referenced from Model layer.

When I run this command in PowerShell :

```
dotnet ef --startup-project ../Eela.Web/ migrations add v1
```

I have this error :

> C:\Users*.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\2.3.4.231\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.targets(40,3): error MSB4062: The
>   "Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.FixedCreateCSharpManifestResourceName" task
>   could not be loaded from the assembly
>   C:\Users*.nuget\packages\xamarin.forms\2.3.4.231\build\portable-win+net45+wp80+win81+wpa81+MonoAndroid10+Xamarin.iOS10+xamarinmac20\Xamarin.Forms.Build.Tasks.dll.
>   Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Build.Utilities.v4.0,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.
>   The system cannot find the file specified. Confirm that the
>   declaration is correct, that the assembly and all its dependencies are
>   available, and that the task contains a public class that implements
>   Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask. [.....\Eela.Model.csproj]

Even I'm using :

```
<PackageTargetFallback>$(PackageTargetFallback);portable-win+net45+wp8+win81+wpa8</PackageTargetFallback>
```

in Data layer but the problem is persisted,

Is there any way to resolve this problem ?

Answer (score 1):

I did not use the migrations with EntityFramework core in a xamarin forms app.  I just used

```
await db.Database.EnsureCreatedAsync()
```

If you add a .net core console app to the solution I think you can you can use migrations.

Comment: What is that mean ? I created a console app and I added model layer reference to it and the problem was persisted .